# A simple proof of the Weyl algebra's rigidity.

Tags: reference-request, cohomology, weyl-algebra, deformation-theory, hochschild-cohomology

I am wondering if there is a nice presentation of the Hochschild cohomology of $A_n$ the Weyl algebra. It is known that $H^m(A_n,A_n)=0$ for $m>0$, and thus it is rigid. A proof can be found [in Sridharan](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1961-100-03/S0002-9947-1961-0130900-1/S0002-9947-1961-0130900-1.pdf), but this proof seems to be doing a lot more and is fairly complicated.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to see this fact specifically. Essentially, I am being a bit lazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(I write $HH^\bullet(\Lambda)$ what you write $H^\bullet(\Lambda,\Lambda)$. When I become Emperor of Notation, everyone will!)

Since $A_n\cong A_1\otimes\cdots\otimes A_1$, the Künneth formula for Hochschild cohomology (which is proved in Cartan-Eilenberg, Theorem XI.3.1, for example) tells you that $HH^\bullet(A_n)\cong HH^\bullet(A_1)^{\otimes n}$. It is enough, then, to compute $HH^\bullet(A_1)$.

The computation of the whole of $HH^\bullet(A_1)$ is not difficult to carry out directly.

You can climb on the shoulders of others and do the following, too. First, it is easy to check that the center of $A_1$ is $k$, so that $HH^0(A_1)=k$. Second, Jacques Dixmier shows, in his *Algèbres enveloppentes*, that every derivation of $A_1$ is inner, so that $HH^1(A_1)=0$. Finally, the algebra $A_1$ is a Calabi-Yau algebra of global dimension $2$, so in particular it satisfied van den Bergh duality and $HH^2(A_1)=HH_0(A_1)$. The latter vector space is $A_1/[A_1,A_1]$, and a pleasurable computation shows this is zero.

Alternatively, in view of Calabi-Yau-ness of $A_n$, now of global dimension $2n$, we have that $HH^\bullet(A_n)=HH_{2n-\bullet}(A_n)$, and a theorem of Wodzicki tells us that $HH_{2n-\bullet}(A_n)$ is isomorphic to the algebraic de Rham cohomology of $n$-dimensional affine space $\mathbb A^n$, which is just $k$. This way we get $HH^\bullet(A_n)=k$ in one big swoop.

Comment: You're a cool dude. And to be honest, I also prefer HH. Thanks. :)

Comment: I am pretty sure I had an argument avoind *all* computation starting from Block's theorem that tells us that the inclusion $k\to A_n$ induces an isomorphism $HC_\bullet^{\mathrm{per}}(k)\to HC_\bullet^{\mathrm{per}}(A_n)$ and various commutative diagrams, but I cannot see what it was now :/

Comment: @Mariano, in your paper on cohomology of GWAs, does your result hold for higher "dimensional" GWAs(I mean multiple central elements and automorphisms)? I may be being dumb. 

Comment: Additionally, after finding this paper: I reiterate my previous comment. 

Comment: @Bischof: regarding GWAs: the method should work, but I don't know what the end result will be. In particular, you surely can get a resolution by the same means.

Comment: @Mariano, presumably you'll need some condition on the underlying ring similar to your condition that it is polys over one var, and that the central elements are all just series in this variable. Blah blah blah. There is some irony about this entire situation, in particular, I asked the question(on GWAs) above to my advisor, and then asked this question on MO because I wondered about rigidity of hyperbolic algebras(which are GWAs). I guess what I am trying to say is "thanks", or something like that...

Comment: Don't hesitate to contact me off-MO on the siubject :)

Comment: Actually you don't need to compute $ A1/[A1,A1]$ since it can be shown that: if $HH^1(A)\cong 0$ then $A$ is projective as an $A^e$-module.  Moreover in the case the algebra $A$ is unital, such as the case of the $A_n$ this is the same as $HH^i(A)\cong 0$ for positive $i$ (since, $HH^i(A)\cong Ext_i^{A^e}(A,A)\cong$ because $A$ is projective).  


Btw, that comment at the beginning is amazing emperor :P

Comment: oh, and the part about the Wodzicki theorem is quite cool, but its alot to juse use my remark above and then note that $HH^0(A)\cong Z(A)$ and it is easy to see that $Z(A)\cong k$.  
I do admit my approach is less mathematically elegant but its a tiny bit quicker and requires much less background.

Comment: It is not true that HH^1(A)=0 implies A is a projective bimodule. It is very easyy to construct counterexamples for that claim. (It is true that if H^1(A,M)=0 for *all* A-bimodules M, then A is projective, but that is rather irrelevant here) In any case, the Weyl álgebras are definitely not projective as bimodules over themselves.

Answer (score 11):

Since the Weyl algebra is a deformation of the polynomial ring in two variables, there is a short transparent proof using deformation theory, cf. M. Gerstenhaber and A. Giaquinto, On the cohomology of the Weyl algebra, the quantum plane, and the q-Weyl algebra, [arXiv:1208.0346](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0346).

Comment: Thanks Murray. After asking this question many moons ago, I chatted with Anthony about this. I also chatted with you about this once, long ago. I appreciate the reference, however.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Professor Gerstenhaber.

Comment: Although I'm not certain I've looked at this paper carefully, so I am again thankful for the reference.